# how to apply validation to all tags with specific classes?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form in a loop. All form fields must be filled at least once.
For fields, I added a class. Next, I check if there is a value.

my form (laravel blade)

```
@foreach($locales as $locale)
<div>
    <label for="{{$locale.'[title]'}}">Title</label>
        <input class="valid" name={{$locale.'[title]'}} 
               type="text"
               id="{{$locale.'[title]'}}">

   <label for="{{$locale.'[text]'}}" class="control-label">Text </label>
       <textarea class="valid"
                 name="{{$locale.'[text]'}}"
                 id="{{$locale.'[text]'}}">
       </textarea>
</div>
@endforeach
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
                validForm();
            });

            function validForm() {
                $('.valid').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                       $result = true;
                       return false;
                    } else {
                        $result = false;
                    }
                });
                if (!($result)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
```

In this part of the code `if ($(this).val()) {$result = true;return false;}`, if, for example, input has a value, then the loop exits and the textarea is not checked.
But if I remove `return false`, then all fields of all forms will be required to be filled (how many times the loop will draw them).

How can I check if all fields of at least one form have values?
Or how to get out of the loop correctly?
Now the form has 2 fields, but in the future there may be more, that is, the check should be universal.

Comment: `for="text"` is incorrect. You don't have `#text` Should be `for="{{$locale.'[text]'}}"` given `$locale.'[text]'` is the correct way  to do it...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right, I wrote incorrectly here. There is no such error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to an parent div like this:

```
@foreach($locales as $locale)
<div class="part-form">
  <label for="{{$locale.'[title]'}}">Title</label>
    <input class="valid" name={{$locale.'[title]'}} 
           type="text"
           id="{{$locale.'[title]'}}">

  <label for="{{$locale.'[text]'}}" class="control-label">Text </label>
   <textarea class="valid"
             name="{{$locale.'[text]'}}"
             id="{{$locale.'[text]'}}">
   </textarea>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And then check if any `part-form` is full filled.

Example based on your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
            validForm();
        });

        function validForm() {
            $(".part-form").each(function() {
              var empty = $(this).find(".valid").filter(function() {
                return $(this).val().trim() == "";
              });
              if (!empty.length) {
                $result = true;
                return false;
              }
            })
            if (!($result)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
```